# Need to build products page with filters (price, category,..etc)

Tags: plugin-craftcommerce, filter

I need to build a product page with filters on the side to filter the product by : price ( less than 100, between 100 and 200 , between 200 and 300 , greater than 300 ) 
and also by category,
Category only now is working :

```
{% if category is defined %}
   {% paginate craft.commerce.products.relatedTo(category).limit(limit) as products %}
{% endif %}
```

Not using variants right now.

regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am using https://isotope.metafizzy.co/filtering.html for this. Really easy to use